# How to copy target's all runtime dependencies after build process in CMake?

Tags: cmake, dependencies, post-build

I'm trying to organize auto-copying runtime dependencies of executable targets to its built directories.

As case I use **GTest** for unit-testing that is linking as shared libraries. After building if I try to launch unit-tests there will be an error like "*gtest.dll isn't found*". With other external dependencies the same problem (as with local where target is shared library).

I can just add every external library to install process after linking and run tests in that directory but it isn't a practical way as launching **CTest**.

I wanted to use `file(GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES)` but it must be called after build and I didn't find `INSTALL(CODE)` analog for *POST_BUILD* stage.

Just coping `DLLs` with `add_custom_command` don't work too because of possible dependency inheritance.
For example, **A** depends on **B** that depends on **C**. If I try to make dependency copying by this approach then only **B** will be copied in *POST_BUILD* process of **A**.

I don't like to store all built artifacts in one directory because it creates a mess and could create collisions in the future.

Comment: Use CMake 3.21 and the new `install(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY_SET)` command instead of plain `file(GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES)`: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html?highlight=install#runtime-dependency-set

Comment: @Alex Reinking I read about it and agree that it's better but I want to copy files at POST_BUILD step, not INSTALL step. It will be great if CMake has an alternative of the functionality for required task.

Answer (score 3):

Found out a solution but it's not portable and only works in Windows.

In **CMake** version 3.21 there is a new [TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS) generator expression that returns all runtime dependencies of runtime target as a list of file paths.
The expression can be used in [ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) command at *POST_BUILD* stage.

There are targets of a shared library *SomeLib* and a test executable *SomeLib_tests* in project. The targets of GTest shared libraries are found by [FIND_PACKAGE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) function.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(ExampleProject)

add_library(SomeLib SHARED
            "include/SomeLib/api.h"
            "src/SomeLib/api.cpp")
target_include_directories(SomeLib PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")


find_module(GTest COMPONENTS gtest gtest_main REQUIRED)

add_executable(SomeLib_tests
               "ut/api_tests.cpp")
target_link_libraries(SomeLib_tests
                      PRIVATE SomeLib
                      PRIVATE GTest::gtest GTest::gtest_main)

gtest_add_tests(TARGET SomeLib_tests)
```

At this step, if I call **CTest** under Windows there will be an error like "gtest.dll isn't found".

It's needed to copy all dependencies of the executable to its directory. It can be achieved by calling [ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) in conjunction with the [TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS) expression. The target directory is gotten from [TARGET_FILE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#informational-expressions) generator expression.

```
add_custom_command( TARGET SomeLib_tests POST_BUILD
                    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                        $<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:SomeLib_tests>
                        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:SomeLib_tests>
                    COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS)
```

With that, if I build the project and call **CTest** again the tests will run as expected.

Comment: FYI CMake 3.27 added [$<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLL_DIRS>](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_RUNTIME_DLL_DIRS), intended for use in batch files to set the `PATH`.

Comment: @alexchandel It looks promising. Right now I don't work with CMake project but will keep in mind. Thanks