# How to integrate CTest with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, dll, ctest

I have been following the guide from:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-160

However I fail to understand how to integrate the ctest mechanism in Visual Studio 2019. Right now my shared library (dll) is not found upon execution (only on Windows):

[image]

Here is the simple project setup:

```
> cat .\CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
project (p LANGUAGES C)
set(CMAKE_C_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden)
set(CMAKE_VISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN 1)
add_subdirectory ("src")
enable_testing()
add_subdirectory ("tests")
```

And then src is simply:

```
> cat .\src\CMakeLists.txt
add_library(foo SHARED foo.c foo.h)
target_include_directories(
  foo PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${p_SOURCE_DIR}/src>
)
```

finally tests is:

```
> cat .\tests\CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(footest footest.c)
target_link_libraries(footest PRIVATE foo)
add_test(NAME footest COMMAND footest)
```

---

Running the above under WSL works as expected:

```
$ make && make test
[ 50%] Built target foo
[100%] Built target footest
Running tests...
Test project /mnt/c/Users/malat/CMakeProject1/bin-gcc
    Start 1: footest
1/1 Test #1: footest ..........................   Passed    0.01 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.03 sec
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A modern approach to this issue seems to `TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS`:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS

Documentation suggest to use:

```
find_package(foo CONFIG REQUIRED) # package generated by install(EXPORT)

add_executable(exe main.c)
target_link_libraries(exe PRIVATE foo::foo foo::bar)
add_custom_command(TARGET exe POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy -t $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:exe> $<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:exe>
  COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
)
```

Watch out that the `-t` flag which seems to have been introduced lately.

- https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/23543

Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/73550650/136285
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68908653/136285

---

When using Visual Studio 2019, you may need to change the default cmake version used:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58774277/136285

Comment: Note: `TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS` was added in version 3.21 which contradicts your stated "minimum" version of 3.8. Remember, `cmake_minimum_required` is for _backwards_ compatibility, not _forwards_ compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

As of CMake 3.27, you should use the [`TARGET_RUNTIME_DLL_DIRS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_RUNTIME_DLL_DIRS) generator expression, along with the [`ENVIRONMENT_MODIFICATION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/ENVIRONMENT_MODIFICATION.html) test property to set up your tests for running, rather than by copying the DLLs anywhere.

To do this, simply add the following code to your `tests\CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
set_tests_properties(
    footest
    PROPERTIES
    ENVIRONMENT_MODIFICATION "PATH=path_list_append:$<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLL_DIRS:footest>"
)
```

On non-DLL platforms, this will do nothing, as intended. On those platforms, RPATH takes over.

This improves on Corristo's answer by not requiring updates when you add dependencies to your tests. It also works with `IMPORTED` targets. It also avoids issues with setting `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` in `FetchContent` scenarios.

Comment: A bunch of directories are being added at runtime without a clear control on which dll is being loaded. If case of duplicate `png.dll` you'll have a hard time debugging which one is being loaded IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

In contrast to Linux where additional search paths for libraries can be embedded into an executable (via RPATH or RUNPATH), on Windows the only places the loader looks for .dll files is next to the executable, in directories in the `PATH` environment variable and in C:\System32.

So in order for the test executable to find `foo.dll` you either need to ensure that they are located in the same directory, or add the directory the library is in to the `PATH` when running the tests.

You can have CMake put them into the same directory by setting the `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` property, which is initialized to the value of the `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` variable. If you set that variable before the first target is defined then both the .dll and the .exe will end up in the same directory. For example, you can add

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin" CACHE PATH "")
```

to the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file before the `add_subdirectory ("src")` call.

Alternatively, you can modify the PATH variable when running the tests. This can also be necessary if your test depends on libraries that aren't built by your project, where setting `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` alone won't be sufficient. To do so, with CMake 3.22 and later you can set the `ENVIRONMENT_MODIFICATION` property on the test after the `add_test` call:

```
set_tests_properties(footest
  PROPERTIES
    ENVIRONMENT_MODIFICATION "PATH=path_list_append:$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:foo>"
)
```

Comment: If a child project sets `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` as a cache variable in a FetchContent scenario, as shown above, then on the **second** configure, that setting will impact the parent project's targets (assuming it did not set the variable). It will also affect sibling projects on the first configure.

Comment: @AlexReinking That is true, but I prefer users to be able to override it by setting it on the command line to hard-coding it as a scoped variable where usersrs (or parent projects) no longer are able to control the output directory of all artifacts.

Comment: Then guard setting the normal variable with an `if (NOT DEFINED ...)` check?